# How to create MatchQueryDescriptor using field name as a string?

Tags: nest, elasticsearch-net

After upgrading Nest from 5.4 to 6.2 I could not find the right syntax to create MatchPhraseQueryDescriptor using known field name as a string. It appears that .Field() method no longer takes a string but takes an object path instead.

What is the easiest way to re-write following Nest 5.4 snippet for Nest 6.2 ?

```
var matchPhrase = new MatchPhraseQueryDescriptor<MyType>()
  .Field("MyField")
  .Query("MyQuery");
```

?

Answer (score 0):

`MatchPhraseQueryDescriptor<T>` accepts `Field` or `Expression<Func<T, object>>` as parameters to `.Field(...)`, which it inherits from [`FieldNameQueryDescriptorBase`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/6.2.0/src/Nest/QueryDsl/Abstractions/FieldName/FieldNameQueryDescriptorBase.cs#L18-L21):

```
public abstract class FieldNameQueryDescriptorBase<TDescriptor, TInterface, T>
    : QueryDescriptorBase<TDescriptor, TInterface>, IFieldNameQuery
    where TDescriptor : FieldNameQueryDescriptorBase<TDescriptor, TInterface, T>, TInterface
    where TInterface : class, IFieldNameQuery
    where T : class
{
    Field IFieldNameQuery.Field { get; set; }

    bool IQuery.IsVerbatim { get; set; }

    bool IQuery.IsStrict { get; set; }

    public TDescriptor Field(Field field) => Assign(a => a.Field = field);

    public TDescriptor Field(Expression<Func<T, object>> objectPath) =>
        Assign(a => a.Field = objectPath);
}
```

There is an implicit operator that converts from `string` to `Field`.